P-equitable graph partition
I am now conducting a research in regards to p equitable graph partition problem. I need to use LP techniques to kernelize this problem parametrized by vertex cover.  In basic definition of such problem all partition have a size n+-1. but I want to relax the problem and come up with a way to add some vertices to initial graph so that all partition will be of same size. I need a way to add them in such a manner so that if initial graph  yielded "yes"(partitioning possible) than its extended by me version  will still yield "yes". And same for "no".
So far I came to idea that vertices can be added in a way that they duplicate existing edge between two supposable  partition, not to break connectivity. But there is no proper proof on my side that this relaxation does not break output of partition.
